# Как отследить левый и правый клик мыши, одновременно?

Tags: java, javafx, mouse-event

JavaFX. Как отследить левый и правый клик мыши, одновременно. Т.е. не отдельные клики, а одновременное нажатие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встроенной поддержки обработки одновременного нажатия двух кнопок, судя по всему нет.

Рабочий вариант, как уже написал @MBo: обрабатывать нажатие и отпускание левой и правой кнопки и устанавливать флаг в случае если обе кнопки нажаты одновременно.

Так мы можем отследить как одиночное нажатие так и двойное:

```
//флаг для отслеживания одновременного нажатия
private boolean wereBothButtonsPressed = false;

private void onMousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    //при нажатии проверяем нажаты ли обе кнопки
    wereBothButtonsPressed = e.isPrimaryButtonDown() && e.isSecondaryButtonDown();
}

private void onMouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.isPrimaryButtonDown() || e.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
        //если какая-то из кнопок нажата, то ничего не делаем
        return;
    }
    if (wereBothButtonsPressed) {
        //нажаты обе кнопки
        System.out.prinln("Both buttons");
    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
        //только левая
        System.out.prinln("Only primary");
    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
        //только правая
        System.out.prinln("Only secondary");
    }
}
```

Есть похожий вопрос на английском ([How to make an event for left & right click at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040480/how-to-make-an-event-for-left-right-click-at-the-same-time/49917545)) там никто ничего лучшего не предложил.

Comment: на удивление стабильно работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Записать последовательность событий от первого нажатия кнопки до последнего отпускания. По приходу последнего события отпускания принять решение, какое именно действие выполняется. Если были обе одновременно в нажатом состоянии - выполнить соответствующее действие

Comment: я думал об этом, но это какой-то велосипед получается. Неужели нет встроенной поддержки одновременных нажатий.

Comment: Вряд ли где такое есть - слишком замудрёный получается для пользователя интерфейс